# What are unital maps?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, density-operator

In quantum information, one defines an [unital map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unital_map) as the one that preserves the identity operator $\epsilon (I) = I$. A popular example is the so-called *amplitude damping channel*. My question is,

> what is the physical meaning of an unital map?

Comment: The title of your question is highly misleading.

Answer (score 2):

A CP map 
$$
\mathcal E(\rho) = \sum A_i \rho A_i^\dagger
$$
is unital if and only if
$$
\sum A_i A_i^\dagger = I\ ,
$$
this is, the matrix
$$
(A_1\ A_2\ \cdots A_K)
$$ 
has orthonormal rows.